Powershell: How Do I Open URL with CefSharp / Chromium
We have some SQL reports in our production environment that are currently being executed using scheduled tasks. This isn't very common. I want to streamline the process. So, I wrote a PowerShell script to address this. The simplest approach was to utilize: New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser. However, our reporting server is optimized for Chrome, so there are some static issues.
i found a question here, but this didn't solve this too.
    Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Monitor_Produktion\packages\CefSharp.Common.123.0.60\lib\net462\CefSharp.Core.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Monitor_Produktion\packages\CefSharp.WinForms.123.0.60\lib\net462\CefSharp.WinForms.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Monitor_Produktion\packages\CefSharp.Common.123.0.60\lib\net462\CefSharp.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Monitor_Produktion\packages\CefSharp.Common.123.0.60\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll"

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'None'
    $form.WindowState = 'Maximized'
    $form.Name = "ProduktionsMonitor"

    $browser = New-Object CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser
    $browser.Load("www.google.de")
    $form.Controls.Add($browser)
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

I get the following error-message:

Could not load file or assembly
'C:\temp\Monitor_Produktion\packages\CefSharp.Common.123.0.60\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'.

Is it possible to solve this issue with powershell? Did I forget something?

Try starting schedule tasks using Run As and use same account that is being used when working.  The schedule tasks are being start from a different account than the one you are using.

May, i think i forgot a little bit. The sheduledTask opens Chrome in "kiosk"-Mode. After an hour it opens another tab in kiosk-mode. So my clients had 1000 tabs with the same information. At first i add an action with stop-process and kill chrome befor opening ist again. But i want to have only a script with an timer that reloads the page. (sorry for my bad english :) )

You would need an event/command on the webpage to refresh the page.

Do you have all the dependencies? e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/chromiumembeddedframework.runtime.win-x64 Having all the packages in separate folders isn't going to work. Create a folder and copy all the dependencies into it. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29 for a list of files.

Personally I'd recommend creating your own .net librarythat wrapsCefSharp/WinFormsand call that from your powershell script. Then you can useNuget` to manage the package dependencies.
